# Range Validator Working Strangely

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having a strange issue with a validator that is built up in the code behind. I am using it to restrict the entry of the text box when a product has a minium order qty.

```
Dim oQtyBoxValidation As RangeValidator
oQtyBoxValidation = New WebControls.RangeValidator
oQtyBoxValidation.ID = "qtyBoxValidation_" & Trim(oDataRow("pno"))
oQtyBoxValidation.ControlToValidate = Trim(oDataRow("pno"))
oQtyBoxValidation.ValidationGroup = "vg_" & Trim(oDataRow("pno))

'if min_order_qty set 
If Convert.ToDouble(Trim(oDataRow("min_order"))) > 1 Then
    oQtyBoxValidation.MinimumValue = Convert.ToDouble(Trim(oDataRow("min_order")))
    oQtyBoxValidation.Text = "Quantity must be " & Convert.ToDouble(Trim(oDataRow("min_order"))) & " to 9999"
Else
    oQtyBoxValidation.MinimumValue = "1"
    oQtyBoxValidation.Text = "Quantity must be 1 to 9999"
End If
```

However if I enter the qtys 23 ,2 , 11-22 numbers in the validtor it works but if i enter 3-9 the validation message will not display.

Comment: Where do you add the validators to the page? You have to do that on every postback too, in Page_Init at the latest. Why do you generate them dynamically at all?

Comment: You probably need to set the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx) property

Comment: @TimSchmelter this is a old system mate im trying to push them to mvc believe me its for a dynamically driven category page of products.

Comment: @HansKesting will give that a shot but why would it work for some ranges and not others?

Comment: @HansKesting Thanks that was it cause it was text before and not set to number i think it must been going buy the length of text and not the values but yes thanks it works

Comment: The Text comparison is alphabetical order

Comment: @HansKesting thanks that worked perfect and is now working as expected thanks.